# Weil pairing implementation - low level programming language

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, pairings

I'm just started to studying elliptic curve cryptosystems. My one month-goal is to write a simple signature system based on the Weil-pairing. Some parts of it can be written without deeper understanding, so I decided to start it with the easier parts right now.

I've searched for some ideas on internet, but all I've found was very high level solutions (f.e: SAGE).

Can this system be written in a lower-level language like C? I mean: of course, everything can be done in C, but does it contain parts that are too hard to code it?

For example: finding the derivative of a function is really hard in C.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/relic-toolkit/) or [here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/).